# Windows Azure Web Role - Where does RoleEnvrironment.Changing go?

Tags: azure

Since version 1.3 of the Azure SDK we have to set the configuration publisher within our web application (e.g. global.asax) and not webrole.cs. Is the same true for hooking up `RoleEnvironment.Changed/Changing` events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Your web application runs in a different process than your WebRole.cs meaning you'll need to handle it in one of these (or both) depending on the use case.

An example: Let's assume you have a static property in your global.asax that holds an object. This object has been initialized with information coming from your service configuration. Then   a few days later you modify this configuration in the portal (maybe a connection string). This will raise the RoleEnvironment.Changing event. In that case, you'll need to handle that event in the web application (global.asax) to re-initialize the static object with the new configuration information.

Note that a web application is not always active, it's only fired up after the first request (you can modify this though, but this is the default behavior). Meaning that in some cases you might not be able to handle the event in the web application because the process is not active. If handling the event is crucial for you, you should consider handling it in the WebRole.cs

Comment: thanks for the information. However, I just want to know whether the event handler will fire in webrole.cs still if I change the service configuration file (say through the Azure portal).

Comment: Yes it will. Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg494982.aspx